# Subsetting a Dataframe from a Dataframe with fixed row numbers

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a Dataframe of 20 rows and 50 columns, say as  `data1`. Now I have used `subset` operation and dropped certain columns from data1 and got a new Dataframe of 20 rows and 30 columns as `data2`.

Now I want to get the remaining dataframe of 20 rows and 20 columns as `data3` in a quick way and not by choosing columns individually, how to do it?

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: data1=read.table("airq402.dat", header = F, col.names = c("City1","City2", "Average Fare", "Distance", "Average weekly passengers", "market leading airline", "market share", "Average fare", "Low price airline", "market share", "price"))

data2=subset(data, select = -c(City1,City2,market.leading.airline,Low.price.airline))

data3= subset(data, select = c(City1,City2,market.leading.airline,Low.price.airline))

this is the way I am splitting a dataframe into 2 df keeping rows same..my question is if I have a large df and I want to split it into say 3 df keeping the rows same..how to do it

Comment: Maybe `setdiff` on the column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, you could use `setdiff` to get the names. Consider an example,

```
data3 <- data1[setdiff(names(data1), names(data2))]

data3
#    a  b  d  g  h  i  j
#1  10 10  8  6  9  9  3
#2   6  6  4  3  3  7  9
#3   5  7 10  1 10  5  6
#4   4  9  9  9  2  3  8
#5   1  4  3 10  5  6  4
#6   8  8  1  8  7  8  1
#7   2  5  6  2  8 10  2
#8   7  1  2  7  6  1  7
#9   9  2  7  4  4  2 10
#10  3  3  5  5  1  4  5
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
data1 <- setNames(as.data.frame(replicate(10, sample(10))), letters[1:10])
data2 <- data1[, c(3, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, 
Thanks. Just want to ask that the above operation applies for whenever we have two variables, what about more than 2 variables. suppose in your case there is another data3 as a subset of data1, can I get the data4 which is the remaining part of data1

Comment: @soumyajt In that case, you need to do `data1[setdiff(names(data1), unique(c(names(data2), names(data3))))]`